# Replace all variables with integers

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I am trying to replace all "variables" with integer using standard input.

input string:

> "pq+pq+pqr+4"

Say, I enter 1 for `pq` and 3 for `pqr`.
What I want to get is

> "1+1+3+4"

How could I get this?
Currently, my code also replace `pqr` with `1r`, which is not a valid.

```
// replaces all variables to integer or double
String evalVariables(String line) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)(?:^|\\s+)([a-z]+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    while (m.find()) {
        String targetStr = m.group();
        System.out.println("targetStr: " + targetStr );
        System.out.println("Enter a integer or a double value for the variable ");
        System.out.print("[" + targetStr + "]: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String newStr = sc.next();
        line = line.replaceAll(targetStr, newStr);
        System.out.println("After replacement: "+ line);
        m = p.matcher(line);
        }
    return line;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of saying that there needs to be `^` or `\\s` before variable name, require that `[a-z]+` have word boundaries on both ends, i.e. `\\b`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)(\\b[a-z]+\\b)");
...
line = line.replaceAll("\\b"+targetStr+"\\b", newStr);
```

In addition, you need to move `Scanner` declaration outside the loop:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)(\\b[a-z]+\\b)"); // <<=== Use \b
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // <<== Scanner declared here
while (m.find()) {
    String targetStr = m.group();
    System.out.println("targetStr: " + targetStr );
    System.out.println("Enter a integer or a double value for the variable ");
    System.out.print("[" + targetStr + "]: ");
    String newStr = sc.next();
    line = line.replaceAll("\\b"+targetStr+"\\b", newStr); // <<=== Use \b
    System.out.println("After replacement: "+ line);
    m = p.matcher(line);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/oxWth5)

Answer (score 2):

Use `\b` to define the word boundaries at each side of your variable name in your `replaceAll` in order to indicate that you want to replace a complete word not a sub part of a word, as next:

```
line = line.replaceAll("\\b" + targetStr + "\\b", newStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply sort the patterns you wanna replace based on their length, and then apply them , this will solve your issue. good luck with the implementation.